# Uma função que faça o contrário de uma adição mod 2³²

Tags: python, funções

```
def mod_2to32sub1(x):
    s = 0 # the sum

    while x > 0: # get the digits
        s += x & (2**32-1)
        x >>= 32

    if s > 2**32-1:
        return mod_2to32sub1(s)
    elif s == 2**32-1:
        return 0
    else:
        return s
```

Essa função acima faz o 'adition mod 2^32'.

Por que do código?
Bem, gostaria de pedir vossa ajuda para criar uma função que faça o contrário dessa função, mas tenho dificuldades. Me ajudem a entender como posso estar fazendo isso.

Pra exemplificar melhor, tenho o seguinte número, 554900798. Ele é '9144835390', antes de realizar a adição do modulo 2³². Bem, gostaria de transformar o '554900798' para '9144835390' novamente. Espero que tenha ficado claro.

O que posso estar fazendo?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Como ele faz a "adição" de a definição de adição prevê dois operandos e um resultado? Aí somente um operando está sendo passado

Comment: Um seria x e outro 0. A função é equivalente a '>>> 0' do Javascript. Só que eu queria entender se posso criar uma função inversa(<<<). Me pediram isso no curso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Módulo (restante de divisão) não é uma operação reversível.

Consideremos o caso mais simples com o operador `%`:

```
In [1]: 9144835390 % 2**32
Out[1]: 554900798
```

Aqui observamos que a operação é a mesma, baseado no seu exemplo.

Pra visualizarmos melhor a questão, imagine o seguinte exemplo: Queremos o restante da divisão de 7 por 3.

```
In [2]: 7 % 3
Out[2]: 1
```

O resultado é 1. Mas e o restante da divisão de 10 por 3?

```
In [3]: 10 % 3
Out[3]: 1
```

Também é 1. O mesmo acontece pra 13, 16, etc.

Quer dizer, **existem infinitos números que resultam no mesmo restante pra qualquer dado divisor.** Não é possível reverter a operação, porque informação é perdida no processo.

Se você quiser números que se encaixem nesse perfil, é possível encontrá-los:

```
def gerar_nums(resto, divisor):
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i * divisor + resto
        i += 1

gerador = gerar_nums(1, 3)
for i, num in enumerate(gerador):
    print(num, end=', ')
    if i == 5:
        break

# 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19,
```

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito.